# is it necessary to implement the permissions_descriptor?

Tags: ligo, fa2

With FA2 NFT tokens, is it necessary to implement the permissions_descriptor?
As far as I can see in tzkt, it doesn't look like it's actually being used. Are there any contracts that are actually used?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the tzip-12 specifications for FA2 contracts.
https://gitlab.com/tezos/tzip/-/blob/master/proposals/tzip-12/tzip-12.md#fa2-transfer-permission-policies-and-configuration

There is no strict standard on permission policies for FA2.

Comment: Thank you for your feed back! it's very helpful.
I've read that. I was worried about the implications of the "the FA2 token contract MUST expose consistent" statement.
I'll interpret this sentence as if it were consistent with the implementation.